# Storing Files in Date Format Folders in ADLS Gen2 Using Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I'm working with Azure Databricks and ADLS Gen2, and I receive a number of files daily that I need to store in folders named after their respective dates. Is there a way to create these folders dynamically and upload the files to them using Databricks?

For example, if I receive a file named `file.csv` on April 6th, 2023, I would like to store it in a folder named `2023-04-06`.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce same thing in my environment. As per above requirement.

**Please follow below steps:**

First mount your storage account with azure databricks:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://<container_name>@<stoarge_account>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net":"Access_key"})
```

[image]

**For creating folder dynamically and upload the files, use below code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import shutil

curr_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
fol_path = os.path.join('/mnt',curr_date)
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(fol_path)
```

[image]

**Upload file to folder mount path**

```
file_path = '/FileStore/tables/demo/'

dbutils.fs.mv(file_path,fol_path,recurse=True)
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]